# Is there a workaround for placing placeholders in a textbox in SSRS2005

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

Does anyone know of a workaround for placing placeholders in a textbox in SSRS2005.  I am stuck with SSRS2005 but need to insert database fields into specific places of a textbox containing other static text.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an expression, e.g.:

```
="This is a piece of static text: " & Fields!firstname.Value & " ...and more static text!"
```